# Why is the PDF download failing in a different environment (Galaxy Tab)?

Tags: pdf, download, samsung-mobile

We have an option to download PDF on our mobile website. PDF download is working in one environment, but not working in another environment in Samsung Galaxy tab.

In the environment where it is not working in the Galaxy tab, it's working absolutely fine in both iPad and Desktop. The pdf is generated and the "starting download"  toast message also appears, but after that the download fails.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

OS version : 4.0.3
Browser.     : Native android browser

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this a bit, and I found that it works ok when the downstream/upstream ratio of my internet connection is about 2:1, but it doesn't work when the ratio is 10:1.  Based on that, I'd suggest that the Android end of the transport protocol isn't very good about adapting to highly asymmetric connections.  The upstream path is used for acknowledgements, and a highly asymmetric path can interfere with the protocol - particularly when each end of the protocol is designed by different parties (and not thoroughly tested).  All of your testing is consistent with this theory.  And it is a known issue that transport protocols can sometimes fail to adapt adequately to asymmetric paths.